# AWS Amplify - Creating GraphQL mutation in the Lambda Function and catch the mutation on the frontend with with the Amplify DataStore subscription?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Is it possible to create a new record from the Lambda function and catch it on the frontend with DataStore subscription?

Use case - I'm having a multiple-step process in the lambda function, and after each step, I would like to update the status table with the progress, and the frontend should react to the status change and display the progress to the user.

I tried something like this - in the lambda function, I successfully created a new record with the code that looks something like this:

```
const { Sha256 } = require("@aws-crypto/sha256-js");
const { defaultProvider } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node");
const { SignatureV4 } = require("@aws-sdk/signature-v4");
const { HttpRequest } = require("@aws-sdk/protocol-http");
const { default: fetch, Request } = require("node-fetch");

const GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT = process.env.API_<YOUR_API_NAME>_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT; // had to change this with absolute URL in order to work
const AWS_REGION = process.env.AWS_REGION || "us-east-1";

const mutation = /* GraphQL */ `
  <<some mutation...>>
`;
const variables = {
  <<some variables...>>
}

/**
 * @type {import('@types/aws-lambda').APIGatewayProxyHandler}
 */
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(`EVENT: ${JSON.stringify(event)}`);

  const endpoint = new URL(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT);

  const signer = new SignatureV4({
    credentials: defaultProvider(),
    region: AWS_REGION,
    service: "appsync",
    sha256: Sha256,
  });

  const requestToBeSigned = new HttpRequest({
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      host: endpoint.host,
    },
    hostname: endpoint.host,
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: mutation, variables }),
    path: endpoint.pathname,
  });

  const signed = await signer.sign(requestToBeSigned);
  const request = new Request(GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT, signed);

  let statusCode = 200;
  let body;
  let response;

  try {
    response = await fetch(request);
    body = await response.json();
    if (body.errors) statusCode = 400;
  } catch (error) {
    statusCode = 500;
    body = {
      errors: [
        {
          message: error.message,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  };
};
```

Later, in React, I've tried to listen to the creation of the new record, but it is not catching anything:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = DataStore.observe(Status).subscribe((msg) => {
      console.log(msg.model, msg.opType, msg.element);
    });

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

If this is not possible, or this approach is wrong, could you please suggest the alternatives that are inline with the Amplify best practices.

Comment: What is your end goal in simple English?

Comment: I want to be able to subscribe to data that is inserted to dynamodb inside the lambda function.